# Bootstrap 4 Grid - Children in column do not respect width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I noticed that the children in the bootstrap 4 grid columns can exceed the width of their columns. Is this a bug in Bootstrap 4 or do we have to explicitly set the max-width for its children?

```css
body {
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim dolore vitae fuga debitis recusandae eius nam, neque reprehenderit perferendis corrupti, autem quo nemo consequuntur delectus deleniti quisquam repellat quidem vel!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">hello</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">oasfhsaolf</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, the `col-xs-4` children are behaving just fine - it's the button that's the rebel :) You can see this by inspecting the elements and seeing that those column children are the correct width.

This button behavior is because bootstrap's `.btn` class has `white-space: nowrap`, telling the button to not wrap its enclosed text.

Depending on how you want the button to show, you can add a custom `white-space` css property (like `inherit`) to override the bootstrap styling for the button:

```css
body {
  padding: 12px;
}
.btn.btn-outline-primary {
  white-space: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim dolore vitae fuga debitis recusandae eius nam, neque reprehenderit perferendis corrupti, autem quo nemo consequuntur delectus deleniti quisquam repellat quidem vel!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">hello</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">oasfhsaolf</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah it's kinda strange they would make it `nowrap` by default. Oh well, they probably had their reasons.

Comment: Or we could use the block buttons `.btn-block`

Comment: To be fair, this use case (a button with that much text) is pretty unrealistic for how `.btn` seems intended to function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the button and the bootstrap grid follow the rules

look at this http://jsbin.com/naruqutaqo/edit?html,output